# Select adjacent elements which are nested

Tags: html, css

My syntax looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">content</div>
</div>
```

I want to style child elements which are siblings, like this:

```
.parent .child + .parent .child {
/* Some pretty nice styles */
}
```

Unfortunately this code not work. Does it possible with pure CSS3 or will be available only in future version 4?

Comment: This makes little sense. Elements are either siblings, or they are nested - they can’t be both. What you actually want to achieve here is unclear. Please go read [ask].

Comment: why not have different class names?

Comment: There is no way to go "up and over" in CSS, so you cannot write a rule which assumes the existence of a child on one element, and then tries to select a sibling (or child of sibling) of the parent of that child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent  + .parent .child{
        background-color: red;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">content</div>
</div>
```

This may work. Is that what you want? But it styles childs considering if the parents are following each other. So it doesn't really care about children.

If you really want to select only based on children you may consider a jquery solution (you didn't tag as jquery so...)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear. Add more details. Check These [Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

**Child combinator**
[image]

**Adjacent sibling combinator**

[image]

**General sibling combinator**
[image]

What your css means,

```
.parent .child + .parent .child {
/* Some pretty nice styles */
}
```

Parent with a child followed by another parent with a child. Style will apply to the 2nd parents child.

Ex:

```css
.parent .child + .parent .child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  a
  <div class="child">
    b
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    a
    <div class="child">
      b
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  a
  <div class="child">
    b
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    a
    <div class="child">
      b
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about general sibling combinator, I will try refactor my code now

Answer (score 1):

Since parenthesis don't exist as such in css, it reads,

`.parent .child + .parent .child`

as *"a child inside a parent immediately following a child inside a parent"*. So basically you're selecting :

```
<div class = "parent">
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "parent">
        <div class = "child"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

As a previous commenter pointed out, a solution would be to alternate between parent1 and parent2 and select the divs with `.parent1 + .parent2`.